# Речевая ошибка: "Когда я смотрю в окно, у меня остаются ..."

Tags: лингвистика

Как правильно исправить речевую ошибку в предложении?

> Когда я смотрю в окно, у меня остаются разные впечатления и появляется настроение в зависимости от увиденного.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза настолько неудачная, что её перестраивать не хочется.
Или это домашнее задание? Тогда оно, имхо, тем более неудачное. Править в учебном задании сразу грамматические и стилистические ошибки - это перебор. Больно уж далеко правленная фраза уходит от исходного "образца".

Как-то так наверное:
*Под впечатлением от увиденного в окне у меня меняется настроение.*

Это не идеал, ибо смысл несколько подправлен, но все ж лучше.